# Get serverTime from firebase in grenwich time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using this method to get the time from the firebase server, but if a user have another TimeServer in their phone it cause troubles in my app. Anybody knows how can i do this works getting GreenWich meridian, or get in any country in the world the current time from the server in EUA, i know when user System.currentMilis() this take the Time from the cellphone. But how i can get the value from the double offset.

```
DatabaseReference offsetRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


 @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    double offset = snapshot.getValue(Double.class);
    double estimatedServerTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

Comment: You can use JODA time, it a very good library and it will give you server time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to achieve this you need to change the way in which you set the date and time. The common practice when setting a `TIMESTAMP` is tu use:

```
ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

But note, the field in your model class should look like this:

```
private Map<String, String> timestamp;
```

Because when you are setting the `timestamp`, you setting it as a `map` and when you are retrieving it, you are retrieving it as a `Long`.